# Are transitive verb phrases intransitive verbs?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, phrases, transitivity, intransitive-preposition

Are transitive verb phrases intransitive verbs?

I think I’m asking that probably because some transitive verb phrases goes before prepositions.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give us an example or two?

Comment: I’m thinking a transitive verb phrase might be “make fun” and “make fun” goes before the preposition “of”.

Answer (score 1):

**Verb phrases can be both transitive and intransitive, in just the same way as single-word verbs.**

For example:

> He digs up the road.

"digs up" is a transitive verb phrase, needing an object.

> He cheers up.

"cheers up" is an intransitive verb phrase.

Note that both "dig" and "cheer" are verbs that can be either intransitive or transitive depending on meaning.

So a transitive or intransitive verb phrase may contain a transitive verb or an intransitive verb. There is not a fixed relationship between them.

Comment: I think 'dig up' and 'cheer up' are phrasal verbs. When I said 'transitive verb phrases', I was thinking 'transitive verb phrases' were phrases like 'make fun' or 'take care'. What might you call those phrases?

Comment: Everything I say about verb phrases applies to phrasal verbs. I would also call "make fun" a phrasal verb.